# Colocando classes em elementos de acordo com a URI passada

Tags: php, css, uri

Bom, possuo o seguinte código:

```
<body>
    <?php
    $server = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    $endereco = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'];

    ?>
    <!-- Menu principal -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Quem somos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Loja</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fale conosco</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.Colapso da navegação -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- \.Menu principal -->
```

No caso, a `URI` passada é `localhost/testes/index.php`, eu gostaria de saber se tem como, e como fazer para que, dependendo do que for passado na `URI`, eu `adicionar` ou `remover` `classes` específicas de elementos nessa `navbar`. Procurei em algumas perguntas com respostas do `stack`, porém nenhuma delas me deu uma luz de como fazer ou por onde começar, por isso estou abrindo essa.

Comment: Basta fazer condições com o PHP e dar um echo nas classes que deseja adicionar, se é que eu entendi o que você queria fazer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você não exemplificou as possibilidades das `URI`, você pode fazer algo mesclando as funções [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php) e [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.switch.php):

```
$url = parse_url('http://localhost/testes/index.php');

// Resulta em :
//array (3) {
//   ["scheme"]=>
//   string(4) "http"
//   ["host"]=>
//   string(9) "localhost"
//   ["path"]=>
//   string(17) "/testes/index.php"
// }

$class = '';

switch ($url['path']) {
    case '/testes/index.php':
        $class = 'class-a'
        break;
    case '/testes/create.php':
        $class = 'class-b'
        break;
    case '/testes/update.php':
        $class = 'class-c'
        break;
}
```

Assim a variável `$class` terá o valor referente a cada `URI` definida no `switch`, agora basta exibi-lá na declaração `class`:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default <?=$class?>">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</li>
                <li><a href="#">Quem somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Loja</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fale conosco</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.Colapso da navegação -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

PS: Se não estiver habilitado no seu php o `short_tag`, substitua o `<?=$class?>` por `<?php echo $class ?>`

Comment: No PHP 5.4+ o `<?=` já vem "habilitado" por padrão e pode ser utilizado sem a necessidade do `short_tag`. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Se for o que eu entendi "Folhas de estilo", eis aqui uma idéia que fiz agora para este post:

```
<?php
class Monitora_a_ulr{
$classe_X = null;
function __construct(){
$this->onde = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; $this->guardiao_da_url();
$this->DirPageFolhaEstilos = RAIZ.'/'.FOLHAESTILOS.'/';
}


function guardiao_da_url(){

preg_match('/^(?:[\/]{1}(teste))(?:.*)?$/', $this->onde, $resultado);

if((isset($resultado[1]) == true) AND ($resultado[1] != null)){


$a_folha_de_estilo = $this->DirPageFolhaEstilos.$resultado[1]."_style.css";

//Verificar se a folha de estilo existe
if(file_exists($a_folha_de_estilo) == true){

//Se ela existir atribuir ela à uma variável
$a_folha_de_estilo = $resultado[1];

} else {

//Senão atribuir a folha padrão a essa variavel
$a_folha_de_estilo = 'padrao'."_style.css";

}

}
//Estabelecer o link da folha de estilo
$classe = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/dir_das_classes/'.$a_folha_de_estilo.'" />';

//Retornar um resultado pra ser usado no site
return $this->classe_X = $classe;
}


}
?>
```

USO:

```
<?php
require_once(RAIZ.'/diretorio_das_funcoes_e_classes/Monitora_a_ulr.php');

$determina_a_classe_desta_pagina = new Monitora_a_ulr;

echo $determina_a_classe_desta_pagina->classe_X;
?>
```

Espero que seja isso, desculpe se não é pois foi o que entendi "folha de estilos". Não ficou muito bem elaborado pois eu fiz isso agora após ler o teu post. Fica como uma idéia que pode ser uma semente para algo mais avançado, as possibilidades são imensuráveis.
Eu tenho uma classe que eu chamo de GetdaURL que analisa tudo na URL e lança a base para que as outras classes saibam o que vai mostrar ao usuário. Tudo, absolutamente tudo é filtrado por regex pois tudo passa pelo default.php, não há nada no meu site que se passa fora da raiz.